# Jquery - Populate DropDown box with contents of array fill into dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question when use JQuery to fill data.
I have 10 modal, ever modal is a customer with infor: Select 1 with an array $status = [8 => "return", 16 => "cancel", 17 => "processing"] and Select second with 3 div is 3 select child map with 3 key at Select parents.
So,

1. How to when Select parents nodata then hide 3 div select child,
2. When click into 1 option at Select child fill mapping with Select child respectively, and hide Select child (eg: Select 1: - status == 8, fill and show div have dropdown list 1 of Select 2; status == 16, fill and show dropdown list 2 of Select 2, status == 17, fill and show dropdown list 3 of Select 2,
3. List item and hide unrelated select. When start modal, if Select 1 have data, status == 8, only list 1 of Select 2 will show data ( div 2, 3 will hide) same with another status.
   Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please formulate your questions properly and show us your code so that we have more context.

Comment: Sorry because my code too long, so I post below. ! want use JQuery. when I click into dropdown Return then data fill into Reason with element Select name="reason_return" and similar with Cancel and Processing. At the same time, when Select is Return (value =8) then only show val of <div class="show_reason_return"> and hide  <div class="show_reason_cancel">  and   <div class="show_reason_process">. and similar with another Value 16, 17.

Comment: Instead of commenting here and posting your code as answers, delete them and add them to your original post. Otherwise it will be difficult to see whether your problem is solved or not

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot, my code is working, because post code required Ctrl + K to format but error many times, then I don't post yet!

Answer (score 0):

```
Certainly: Here code page view:
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Status</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="status_pgd" name="status_pgd">
                <option value="8">Return</option>
                <option value="16">Cancel</option>
                <option value="17">Processing</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Reason</label>
        <div class="show_reason_return">
            <select class="form-control" name="reason_return">
                <option value="1">Return A</option>
                <option value="2">Return B</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="show_reason_cancel">
            <select class="form-control" name="reason_cancel">
                <option value="1">Cancel A</option>
                <option value="2">Cancel B</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="show_reason_process">
            <select class="form-control" name="reason_process">
                <option value="1">Processing A</option>
                <option value="2">Processing B</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
and here is code Jquery:`enter code here`
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#status_pgd').change(function () {
                let status_pgd = $(this).val();
                if (status_pgd == 8) {
                    $(".show_reason_return").show();
                    $(".show_reason_cancel").hide();
                    $(".show_reason_process").hide();
                } else if (status_pgd == 16) {
                    $(".show_reason_cancel").show();
                    $(".show_reason_return").hide();
                    $(".show_reason_process").hide();
                } else if (status_pgd == 17) {
                    $(".show_reason_process").show();
                    $(".show_reason_cancel").hide();
                    $(".show_reason_return").hide();
                } else {
                    $(".show_reason_process").hide();
                    $(".show_reason_return").hide();
                    $(".show_reason_cancel").hide();
                }
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            let status_pgd1 = $('#status_pgd').val();
            if (status_pgd1 == 8) {
                $(".show_reason_return").show();
                $(".show_reason_cancel").hide();
                $(".show_reason_process").hide();
            } else if (status_pgd1 == 16) {
                $(".show_reason_cancel").show();
                $(".show_reason_return").hide();
                $(".show_reason_process").hide();
            } else if (status_pgd1 == 17) {
                $(".show_reason_process").show();
                $(".show_reason_cancel").hide();
                $(".show_reason_return").hide();
            } else {
                $(".show_reason_process").hide();
                $(".show_reason_return").hide();
                $(".show_reason_cancel").hide();
            }
        });
```